# Writing a for loop with .map()

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-stream

I have this code which is realized with a for loop. I wanted to write it with a .stream and .map() function. I tried using the .map() function. But unfortunately I get the following error:

> Incompatible types. Required List> but 'collect' was
>   inferred to R: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that
>   Boolean conforms to List inference variable T has incompatible
>   bounds: equality constraints: List lower bounds: Boolean

Here is the old code:

```
 public Iterable<Record> findAll(final List<Long> id) {
        final List<Record> result = new LinkedList<Record>();
        final List<List<Long>> partitions = ListUtils.partition(id, 10);
        for (List<Long> partition : partitions) {
            Iterables.addAll(
                    result,
                    this.repository.findAll(partition) 
            );
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is the code when I use the .map()

```
   public Iterable<Record> findAll(final List<Long> id) {
        final List<Record> result = new LinkedList<Record>();
        final List<List<Long>> partitions = ListUtils.partition(id, 10);

         List<List<Long>> allPartitions = partitions.stream().map(partition ->{
            return Iterables.addAll(result, this.repository.findAll(partition));
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return result;
    }
```

Any suggestion on how I could fix this? or on what I should pay attention?

Comment: Try this `List<List<Long>> allPartitions = partitions.stream().map(partition ->{
            Iterables.addAll(result, this.repository.findAll(partition));
            return result;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @HadiJ I don't see any difference with my code that I wrote, and which didn't work

Comment: `Iterables.addAll(result, this.repository.findAll(partition));` returns boolean while you need to returns `List<Long>` because of that it isn't compatible. so I guess you should return `result` although I don't familiar with guava.

Comment: Or like this `return partitions.stream()
                .flatMap(partition->this.repository.findAll(partition).stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: I think this mapping which I did is not right.  A way which I tried to use the .map() is by adding to the Record like this: 
`public Iterable<Record> findAll(final List<Long> id) {
        final List<List<Long>> partitions = ListUtils.partition(id, 10);
        final List<Record> result = id.stream().map(temp ->{
           return  partitions.forEach(partition -> Iterables.addAll(result, this.platesRepository.findAll(partition)));
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return result;
    }` the result gives me an initialization error, since i didn't got its value yet...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207409/discussion-between-hadi-j-and-dernor00).

Comment: What does `this.repository.findAll(partition)` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `this.repository.findAll(partition)` returns `Iterable<Record>`, you can use

```
public Iterable<Record> findAll(final List<Long> id) {
    return ListUtils.partition(id, 10).stream()
        .flatMap(partition -> StreamSupport.stream(
                this.repository.findAll(partition).spliterator(), false))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This complicated `Stream` construction is only necessary when `findAll` returns an `Iterable` rather than `Collection`. If it returned `Collection`, you could simply use:

```
public Iterable<Record> findAll(final List<Long> id) {
    return ListUtils.partition(id, 10).stream()
        .flatMap(partition -> this.repository.findAll(partition).stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In that regard, you shouldn’t put the same burden on the caller of your method and consider changing the return type from `Iterable<Record>` to `Collection<Record>` or even `List<Record>`.

The other point to consider, is whether performing this operation in these small chunks really has any benefit, when you are retrieving all records anyway.
So why not just use `return this.repository.findAll(id);`…

Comment: It looks more like a cursor use case. (But not very sure of internals with spring boot.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can replase for loop with `forEach`:

```
public Iterable<Record> findAll(final List<Long> id) {
    final List<Record> result = new LinkedList<Record>();
    final List<List<Long>> partitions = ListUtils.partition(id, 10);
    partitions.forEach(partition -> Iterables.addAll(result, this.repository.findAll(partition)));
    return result;
}
```